# ReactJS: AG-GRID: Dynamically Assigning Cell Editor based on metadata

Tags: reactjs, editor, ag-grid-react

I wish to apply a Cell Editor dynamically based on metadata. For example if the row is determined to be numeric (i.e., a row holding integer data), I want to use a Numeric Editor.  For Date, a Date Editor, etc...

I'll only know at run-time the definition of each row and because each row can can hold its own datatype, applying a Cell Editor at the column level won't work if the editor is data type specific (I've tried to define a generic editor at the column level but don't feel I have enough competence to make that happen, and nor do I have enough "real" code to show an example).

Here is my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css';

import NumericEditor from "./numericEditor.jsx";

import DatePicker from 'react-date-picker'


const API = 'http://localhost:53884/api/UserConfig/UI'
var PARMS = '';

class UserConfig extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            columnDefs: [],
            components: null,
            rowData: null,
            isLoading: false,
            error: null,
            config: [],
            heading: "",
            meta: [],
            frameworkComponents: {
                numericEditor: NumericEditor,
                datePicker: DatePicker

            }
        };
        this.onGridReady = this.onGridReady.bind(this);
    }

    onGridReady(params) {
        this.gridApi = params.api;
        this.columnApi = params.columnApi;

        this.gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true });

        axios.get(API + PARMS)
            .then(fubar => {

                const config = fubar.data.config;
                const headerRow = fubar.data.header;
                const rowData = fubar.data.results;
                const meta = fubar.data.meta;

                this.setState({ heading: "User Configuration: Trade Date " + new Date(config.tradeDate).toLocaleDateString("en-US") });

                var newCols = [
                    { headerName: "", field: "attribute", width: 200, hide: true },
                    { headerName: "", field: "displayName", width: 200, resizable: true, sortable: true, filter: true },
                    { headerName: headerRow.value0, field: "value0", width: 100, resizable: true, editable: true },
                    { headerName: headerRow.value1, field: "value1", width: 100, resizable: true, editable: false },
                    { headerName: headerRow.value2, field: "value2", width: 100, resizable: true, editable: false },
                    { headerName: headerRow.value3, field: "value3", width: 100, resizable: true, editable: false },
                    { headerName: headerRow.value4, field: "value4", width: 100, resizable: true, editable: false },
                    { headerName: headerRow.value5, field: "value5", width: 100, resizable: true, editable: false },
                    { headerName: headerRow.value6, field: "value6", width: 100, resizable: true, editable: false },
                    { headerName: headerRow.value7, field: "value7", width: 100, resizable: true, editable: false },
                    { headerName: headerRow.value8, field: "value8", width: 100, resizable: true, editable: false },
                    { headerName: headerRow.value9, field: "value9", width: 100, resizable: true, editable: false },
                ];

                if (headerRow.value0 === null) newCols[2].hide = true;
                if (headerRow.value1 === null) newCols[3].hide = true;
                if (headerRow.value2 === null) newCols[4].hide = true;
                if (headerRow.value3 === null) newCols[5].hide = true;
                if (headerRow.value4 === null) newCols[6].hide = true;
                if (headerRow.value5 === null) newCols[7].hide = true;
                if (headerRow.value6 === null) newCols[8].hide = true;
                if (headerRow.value7 === null) newCols[9].hide = true;
                if (headerRow.value8 === null) newCols[10].hide = true;
                if (headerRow.value9 === null) newCols[11].hide = true;

                this.setState({ rowData, config, columnDefs: newCols, meta });
            })
            .catch(error => this.setState({
                error,
                isLoading: false
            }));
    }

    onCellEditingStarted = params => {
        const { meta } = this.state;

        const attribute = params.data.attribute;

        var cols = this.state.columnDefs;

        const metaRow = meta.find(item => { return item.attribute === attribute });

        if (metaRow.dataType === "datetime") cols[2].cellEditor = "datePicker";
        if (metaRow.dataType === "int") cols[2].cellEditor = "numericEditor";

        this.setState({ columnDefs: cols });

        //NumericEditor(params);

        //alert('Display Name = ' + metaRow.displayName + ',\n'
        //    + 'Display Order = ' + metaRow.displayOrder + ',\n'
        //    + 'Default Value = ' + metaRow.defaultValue + ',\n'
        //    + 'Data Type = ' + metaRow.dataType + ',\n'
        //    + 'Allow Nulls = ' + metaRow.allowNull);
    };

    render() {
        const { heading, rowData, columnDefs } = this.state;

        return (
            <div className="ag-theme-balham" style={{ height: '500px', width: '800px' }} >
                <h2 style={{ paddingLeft: '32px' }}>{heading}</h2>

                <AgGridReact
                    columnDefs={columnDefs}
                    rowData={rowData}
                    onCellClicked={this.onCellClicked.bind(this)}
                    frameworkComponents={this.state.frameworkComponents}
                />
            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default UserConfig;
```

My approach is to leverage **onCellClicked**:

```
    <AgGridReact
        columnDefs={columnDefs}
        rowData={rowData}
        onCellClicked={this.onCellClicked.bind(this)}
        frameworkComponents={this.state.frameworkComponents}
    />
```

to apply the Cell Editor change within the event handler below:

```
onCellClicked = params => {
    const { meta } = this.state;

    const attribute = params.data.attribute;

    var cols = this.state.columnDefs;

    const metaRow = meta.find(item => { return item.attribute === attribute });

    if (metaRow.dataType === "datetime") cols[2].cellEditor = "datePicker";
    if (metaRow.dataType === "int") cols[2].cellEditor = "numericEditor";

    this.setState({ columnDefs: cols });
};
```

Every time a cell is clicked, the datatype is determined for the cell row, and the Cell Editor for column[2] is revised to reflect the cell row datatype.

It feels to me a heavy handed approach but I'm not sure how else to go about staying within the ReactJS/AG-Grid world.

By the way, by the time someone is able to click on a cell, the state for columnDefs has already been set twice: clicking on a cell would represent the 3rd+ time.

**========== EDIT ==========**

I've found that dramatically altering the cols structure will trigger the application to apply my Cell Editor changes. For example when copying my columnDefs into a new array, and I slice a handful of columns rather than taking the entire array:

```
var cols = this.state.columnDefs.slice(0,8);
```

when I set column state,

```
this.setState({ columnDefs: cols });
```

my editor selection kicks in.

Of course I don't want to - nor do I need to - make such a radical change to my column definitions. If I did, I might think to add a new column every time someone clicks a cell, perhaps if the target row datatype isn't the same as the last one clicked. But that seems like a really bad approach.

Another approach, which I've had no success with, is to force an update using either:

```
this.forceUpdate();
this.setState({ state: this.state });
```

but neither seems to be effective here.

I appreciate your feedback - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking for something similar and the ag-grid docs talk about this functionality built-in.
See the "Many Editors One Column" section in the ag-grid docs (v22.0.0): https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/#many-editors-one-column

> **Many Editors One Column**
>
> It is also possible to use different editors for different rows in the same column. Typically an application might check the rows contents and choose an editor accordingly. To configure this set colDef.cellEditorSelector to a function that returns the name of the component to be used as an editor and optionally the custom params to be passed into it
>
> The params that are passed to this function is the same as the params passed to cell editors..
>
> The following example illustrates how to use different editors and parameters in the same column. Note that:
>
> - The column 'Value' holds data of different types as shown in the column 'Type' (numbers/genders/moods).
> - colDef.cellEditorSelector is a function that returns the name of the component to use to edit based on the type of data for that row

```
cellEditorSelector:function (params) {

  if (params.data.type === 'age') return {
      component: 'numericCellEditor'
  };

  if (params.data.type === 'gender') return {
      component: 'agRichSelect',
      params: {values: ['Male', 'Female']}
  };

  if (params.data.type === 'mood') return {
      component: 'agRichSelect'
  };

  return null;
}
```

Comment: Updated link for 2023 https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/cell-editors/#many-editors-one-column